# Is it possible to use @layer utilities in windicss?

Tags: tailwind-css, windicss

I can't find a way to add custom utilities to windicss. On tailwindcss (jit mode) this works very nicely

Working example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/cXjN4t4GH8?file=css

Documentation here:
https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities#using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '@layer' directive in windicss just as you would use them in tailwindcss.
You can also use 'shortcuts' or 'aliases' to add custom utilities in windicss.

Related Links:

[Using directive in windicss](https://windicss.org/features/directives.html#layer)

[Using shortcuts in windicss](https://windicss.org/features/shortcuts.html)

[Using alias config in windicss](https://windicss.org/posts/v30.html#alias-config)